# Why does GCC insert a callq at the begain of a function?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I have a code as below:

```
int foo(void);
int  __attribute__((noinline))  xxx(int a)
{
        return a+3;
}

int my_main(void)
{
    int pos;

    pos = foo();
    if (pos)
            return 1;

    return xxx(3);
}
```

compile it with 'gcc -O3 -g -c main.c', then the result is:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <xxx>:
   0:   8d 47 03                lea    0x3(%rdi),%eax
   3:   c3                      retq
   4:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
   6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   d:   00 00 00

0000000000000010 <my_main>:
  10:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  14:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  19 <my_main+0x9>
  19:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  1b:   75 13                   jne    30 <my_main+0x20>
  1d:   bf 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edi
  22:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  26:   eb d8                   jmp    0 <xxx>
  28:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  2f:   00
  30:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  35:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  39:   c3                      retq
```

Look at the my_main() function, why it has a call to itself (callq  19 )?

Comment: It's not calling itself, that's call to `foo`, which is not linked yet, i.e. the `call` machine code is unfinished, with zero offset at the moment of your disassembly. (you are probably disassembling object file before linking, or using some kind of dynamic shared executable which keeps the calls on zero too, but can't recall of such common platform, so most likely you disassembled object file). Try to run the code and put breakpoint at beginning of `my_main` to see where the call points in final.

Comment: Thank you, I undertand it now.